# Folders at cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/daily-live/

Tags: daily-build

When you open http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/daily-live/ then there are 4 folders with ISO images of Ubuntu.

Two folders are named  current/ 
 and pending/

and two folders named after today's and yesterday's dates.

What are the differences/significance/purpose of the contents of these 4 different folders ?

Comment: Looks like yesterday's and today's. Note the date/time stams show that yesterday's is the "current" one while today's is the "pending" one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There aren't four different folders. There are two named by date, and `current` is the same as the older of these two, and `pending` is the same as the newer of these two.

This seems to be the result of applying some automated testing to the ISOs. From [this blueprint](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/qa-r-staging-iso-testing):

> During the quantal cycle there have been times where the daily ISO
>   images had bug or problems on them, which hit many users and or
>   automated jenkins testing. Ideally we want to prevent users from
>   downloading borked images and hitting/reporting bugs over and over
>   again. We should discuss and possibly implement something to help with
>   this, e.g.:
>
> - consider uploading images to a staging area, running jenkins test and if jenkin tests pass then publish the iso images
> - or for example push jenkin test failure notes to the cdimage / iso-tracker (like the oversize warning)
> - think about potentially yanking borked images from cdimage.u.c
> - communicate "why there was no daily build yet?", e.g. by pushing "FTBFS" notification to iso-tracker & cdimage.u.c
> - communicate respin process in a more automatic way, e.g. on the iso tracker / cdimage.u.c
>
> Objective:
>
> - Try to run some automated testing before the images are published
> - Work with Unity testing team to make sure unity works (hook unity jenkins to be dowstream from the desktop-default jenkins test)

`pending` is this staging area, as can be seen from the notes further down the blueprint page.

As for why have a set of folders based on dates and another set with names, it's easier:

- for scripting to have folders like `current` which always point to the current release,
- to atomically update the folders if `current` and `pending` are symbolic links to folders containing the actual ISOs.